# Date formatting on Action/Object publishing

Tags: facebook, format

With the new Action/Object parts of Open Graph, I'm trying to publish a DateTime formatted absolutely, something like:

"Dave is attending *EventName* on ...
9/28/2011 at 9:30pm"

However, I can only get the date to render in two formats: "123456789" or "3 hours left".

I have created an Object, called Event.  I've given it a custom field Time of type DateTime.
I have created an Action, called Attend, which is associated with an event.

On the Event's page, I'm writing the meta tag using the Event's time in the same format as php time().

In both the Aggregation and the Action, I am trying to output "{event.time}" in the correct format.  Based on [the Formatter section of this page of FB's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units/), I'd think that I could specific a specific date formatter, like date(“F d, Y”).  However, I always get an error like "Invalid format date(“F d, Y”)".

Any ideas how to get proper date formatting?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is `{event.time | date("fb_absolute")}`. This is done to keep consistency with other dates on Facebook.

Comment: fb_absolute doesn't actually output an absolute time for me, is it supposed to?  I get strings like "3 hours left" and "about a week".

Comment: Try older posts. `fb_absolute` tries to be smart about people's consumption of relative dates.

Comment: The nature of our app is such that the date we are trying to render is in the future.  So it sounds like to render these DateTimes accurately, our best bet is to have an Open Graph meta tag with a formatted time using a default time zone for the Event, and lose support for rendering in the viewer's timezone on FB.  (We could still also output a DateTime meta tag to support aggregations based on Event.time)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the bug report. Facebook's date formatting doesn't work well with future dates. I'm looking into it, but for now, yes, just us a string field. It would probably be a good idea to ALSO include the date on the object for when the date formatter starts working for future dates.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported this as a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/198438833569505